# Calculating Elliptic Curve cofactor h

Tags: group-theory, elliptic-curves

An Elliptic Curve in short Weierstrass form over a finite field $F_p$ is given by the equation:

$$y^2 = x^3 + ax + b \mod p$$

To use this curve for cryptographic purposes, in the domain parameters of the curve a point $G$ on the curve is defined. $n$ is the order of the subgroup generated by $G$ and is usually included in the domain parameters of the curve. The cofactor of such a curve is defined as:

$$h = \frac{\#E(F_p)}{n}$$

where $\#E(F_p)$ is the number of all points that satisfy the curve equation and $n$ is the order of the curve.

For most (well-chosen) domain parameters, $h$ can be approximated reasonably well by:

$$h \approx \frac{p}{n}$$

But what's the approach to actually *calculate* $h$ when only $a, b, n, p$ are given that gets around explicit point counting algorithms like Schoof/Elkies?

Comment: What is the order of an elliptic curve?  It may help if you include a specific example with your question (one where $h$ is not $1$) so it's easier to see what everything means (including the $a$ and $b$, which you write but never explain either).

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I didn't know in what level of detail I should present the question -- I've changed it to clear things up.

Comment: Your use of the terminology "order of the curve" is bad, because the set of all points is a group and it is standard to call the size of a group its order. You should call $n$ "the order of $G$" rather than the order of the curve. (I assume $G$ is not a generator of the group $E({\mathbf F}_p)$, since then $h = 1$ and the whole issue becomes silly.)

Comment: You're correct again, the terminology is misleading. $n$ is the order of the subgroup generated by $G$. For Elliptic-Curve-cryptography, $h$ usually is reasonably small ($h \le 8$ for most cases). Since for well-chosen domain parameters, $G$ is a large subgroup of the curve, the approximation works -- but I'm interested if there's an exact solution without involving algorithms like Schoof or SEA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applying [Hasse's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse%27s_theorem_on_elliptic_curves), we find that $h\in[h_{\text{min}},h_{\text{max}}]$ with
$$\begin{align}
h_{\text{min}} &= \frac{p+1 - 2\sqrt{p}}{n} &
h_{\text{max}} &= \frac{p+1 + 2\sqrt{p}}{n} &
\therefore\quad
h_{\text{max}}-h_{\text{min}} &= \frac{4\sqrt{p}}{n}
\end{align}$$
Consequently, if $n>4\sqrt{p}$ (it usually is), the uncertainty of $h$ as quantified above is smaller than $1$, so there is no more than one integer in $[h_{\text{min}},h_{\text{max}}]$.

The solution for $h$ is then the integer nearest to
$$\frac{h_{\text{min}}+h_{\text{max}}}{2} = \frac{p+1}{n}$$
(Reasonably well indeed.)

Comment: This is beautiful! Thank you so much, now I have a hard criterion that I can check ($n > 4 \sqrt p$) before I apply the $h$ shortcut.